# Start developing with Windows IoT

Tags: windowsiot, windows-iot-core-10

I was reading about the prospects of IoT and wan to start with it. So I want to buy a board. The 4 options are specified on the website. But there is this new board named [C.H.I.P.](https://getchip.com/pages/chip) I would like to know whether I can use this? If not, please guide which one is suitable to buy. Can someone please suggest a few resources from where I can learn?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this site is for programming (code) and programmers tools related questions. This is not a hardware recommendation or suitability site. We also don't find or recommend off-site resources, as the [help/on-topic] clearly says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Windows 10 IoT Core only supports 4 boards:

- Raspberry Pi 3
- Raspberry Pi 2
- MinnowBoard MAX
- DragonBoard 410c

You can see a comparison of the boards here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/boardcomparison

I would suggest going with the Raspberry Pi 3 as it has built-in Wi-Fi and Bluetooth.  You can purchase the board separately or get one of the many Starter Kits.  The kit is a good option if you're just starting out.  It will include the Raspberry Pi and many accessories to start learning and building projects.

Adafruit Starter Kit: https://www.adafruit.com/product/3058
SparkFun Starter Kit: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13826
Microsoft Store (board only): https://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/en_US/pdp/productID.334851400

Just remember that Windows 10 IoT Core requires a Class 10 microSD card.  Some of the kits may have slower cards.